# What are some options for a small organization's contact management system?

Tags: email, database

I would like to implement some sort of contact database management system within a small company.

At this point I have roughly 200 contacts but I see a prospecting database could grow over 500 but probably not more than 1000.

I would like contacts to be organized in some containing database.  Within the container database there are organizational groups.  A contact may belong to more than one group.

I would like contacts to be searched and sorted by things such as name, company, organizational group, etc.

I would like the ability to do mail merge, both email and snail mail.

When sending emails, I would only like each recipient to see only his or her own email address, even if the email was sent to a distribution list with many emails on it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you presently use MS Exchange?

Comment: Yes.  It be nice to keep it all within Exchange, but I do not think Public Folders offers all the features I would like.  Could these features be provided by Public Folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it may be overkill to start, SugarCRM is probably a good fit for you:
http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/

It has an open source version, you can run yourself, or you can have someone else host it for you. It can certainly grow up to do a lot for you, keeping up with sales leads, contact management, etc. Its big thing I think is customization if you ever get into that.

They have a demo that you should try to see if it is something that could work for you.

Comment: Sugar's great - we use it and love it.  very customizable and *free*

Comment: and there's vtiger which is a fork of Sugar, the same - only more free as they don't try to sell you the 'pro' version :)

Comment: If you have Exchange Vtiger would be the better choice because the Outlook plugin is free. The same thing for Sugar is quite expensive.